# Problem loading view with MEF and ExportAttribute

Tags: wpf, mef

I have a WPF app and I'm trying to use MEF to load viewmodels and view. 
I can't successfully load Views.
The code:

```
public interface IContent
{

    void OnNavigatedFrom( );

    void OnNavigatedTo( );

}

public interface IContentMetadata
{
    string ViewUri { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
public class ExtensionMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public string ViewUri { get; private set; }

    public ExtensionMetadataAttribute(string uri) : base(typeof(IContentMetadata))
    {
        this.ViewUri = uri;
    }
}

class ViewContentLoader 
{


    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IContent, IContentMetadata>> ViewExports
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public object GetView(string uri)
    {
        // Get the factory for the View. 
        var viewMapping = ViewExports.FirstOrDefault(o =>
         o.Metadata.ViewUri == uri);

        if (viewMapping == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
             String.Format("Unable to navigate to: {0}. " +
                "Could not locate the View.",
                uri));

        var viewFactory = viewMapping.CreateExport();
        var view = viewFactory.Value;
        return viewFactory;

    }
}
```

I supposed to use this code like this:

1)Decorate a User control

```
[Export(typeof(IContent))]
[ExtensionMetadata("CustomPause")]
  [PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
  public partial class CustomPause : Page , IContent, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    public CustomPause()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

2) Compose the parts:

```
var cv = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
var mef = new ViewContentLoader();
cv.ComposeParts(mef);
```

3) Load the view at runtime given a URI, for example:

```
private void CustomPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vc = GlobalContainer.Instance.GetMefContainer() as ViewContentLoader;

        MainWindow.MainFrame.Content = vc.GetView ("CustomPause");
    }
```

Problem is this line in the GetView method fails:

```
    var viewMapping = ViewExports.FirstOrDefault(o =>
     o.Metadata.ViewUri == uri);
```

The query fails and so viewMapping is null but composition seems ok and I can see that ViewExports contains an object of type:

```
{System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory<EyesGuard.MEF.IContent, EyesGuard.MEF.IContentMetadata>[0]
```

I don't know where I'm wrong. Do you  have a clue?

Gianpaolo

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot this

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
```

in the MetadataAttribute